# Int Array Byte Ordering over Network

Tags: arrays, int, endianness

I know this might be kind of a stupid question, but if I were to send an int array over a network, would I need to use byte ordering? In other words, say i have int a, b, c, d and int e [4]

e[1] = a; e[2] = b; e[3] = c; e[4] = d;

now i send e using: write(socket, e, sizeof (e));

Would the receiver read it in order? Or would I need to use htonl for a,b,c,d before storing in the array? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the receiver is expecting `int`s in network byte order, then yes, you're going to have to put each `int` into network byte order before sending it.

Comment: The receiver is expecting an int array of the same size. e.g int x[4]

Answer (score 0):

The network is not going to care about the byte ordering, but the application hosting the receiving socket will.  If the sending application uses little-endian byte order and the receiving application uses big-endian, then you will have to do the necessary byte reversals.